# Java Rest app problem with printing results in HTML

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am a student and I have to develop a rest app using Java Spring, and the app is an online marks register. I have a StudentController class where I implemented a method in Java to show all the subjects which a student has and the grades related to each subject. I have an array list of hash maps that link a subject with the grades related to it. My problem is that I have to display the results from the Hash Maps from inside the list in the Html and even though I tried some things from the internet, it does not work. Can you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Here is the Java method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "student")
    public ModelAndView showGrades()
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        List<Subject> subjects = subjectRepo.findAll();

        Student student = new Student();
        Person person = session.getUser();

        ArrayList<HashMap<Subject, ArrayList<Integer> >> grades = new ArrayList<HashMap<Subject, ArrayList<Integer> >>();

        student.setName(person.getName());
        student.setAccount(person.getAccount());

        for(int i=0; i<subjects.size(); i++){
            HashMap<Subject, ArrayList<Integer> > mappingGrades = new HashMap<Subject, ArrayList<Integer>>();
            Random rand = new Random();
            ArrayList<Integer> studentGrades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            studentGrades.add(rand.nextInt(10));
            studentGrades.add(rand.nextInt(10));
            studentGrades.add(rand.nextInt(10));
            mappingGrades.put(subjects.get(i), studentGrades);
            student.setGrades(mappingGrades);
            grades.add(mappingGrades);
        }

        modelAndView.addObject("grades", grades);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

And here is the HTML code including my try for printing:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Site made with Mobirise Website Builder v4.11.4, https://mobirise.com -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="generator" content="Mobirise v4.11.4, mobirise.com">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/logo4.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <title>Student</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/web/assets/mobirise-icons/mobirise-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tether/tether.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dropdown/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/theme/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preload" as="style" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">




</head>

<body>
  <section class="header1 cid-rLBDn2JTwv" id="header16-9">





    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-10 align-center">
          <h1 class="mbr-section-title mbr-bold pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-1">
            GRADES
          </h1>

          <p class="mbr-text pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-5">
            Subjects and related grades.
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class="engine"><a href="https://mobirise.info/s">bootstrap theme</a></section>
  <section class="services5 cid-rLBDGcNu8T" id="services5-b">
    <!---->

    <!---->
    <!--Overlay-->

    <!--Container-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!--Titles-->
        <div class="title pb-5 col-12">


        </div>
        <!--Card-1-->
        <div class="card px-3 col-12">
          <div class="card-wrapper media-container-row media-container-row">
            <div class="card-box">
              <div class="top-line pb-3">
                <h4 class="card-title mbr-fonts-style display-5">
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <form action="student" method="showGrades">

                    <div th:each="map : ${grades}">
                        <div th:each="mapEntry : ${map}">
                          <span th:text="${mapEntry.key}"></span> =
                          <span th:text="${mapEntry.value}"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </h4>
                <p class="mbr-text cost mbr-fonts-style m-0 display-5">
                  $400
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="bottom-line">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Card-2-->

        <!--Card-3-->

        <!--Card-4-->

        <!--Card-5-->

        <!--Card-6-->

        <!--Card-7-->

        <!--Card-8-->

        <!--Card-9-->

        <!--Card-10-->

        <!--Card-11-->

        <!--Card-12-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/tether/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/smoothscroll/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/dropdown/js/nav-dropdown.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/dropdown/js/navbar-dropdown.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/touchswipe/jquery.touch-swipe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you supplied the value of mapEntry.key is a Subject object and the value of mapEntry.value is an ArrayList. You need to tell thymeleaf how to output those objects. If Subject has a proper toString method it will work as you expect but an ArrayList will not print properly. You need to use another nested each statement or you need to join it into a single string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to use another nested each statement, but sincerely I do not know exactly how to make it work since I am very new with thymeleaf, its the first time I use it.